# php/jquery : Unable to save cropped image

Tags: php, jquery, crop, cropper

So I am creating this page that allows the user to crop his image and then save it on his file, however, although when I click on the button crop, it shows me the alert message "upload success", it doesn't get saved on my folder. So Im guessing there is a problem with the file `upload.php` however, for the sake of it, i will provide both the files here. Please let me know whats wrong. Thanks!
First file named h.php

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="cropper.css">
<script src="cropper.js"></script>

<img id="image" style="width: 250px;" src="bg.JPG">
<script>
    $("#image").cropper();

    function crop(){
        $("#image").cropper('getCroppedCanvas').toBlob(function(blob) 
        {
            var formdata= new FormData();

            formdata.append('croppedImage', blob);
            $.ajax('upload.php',
            {
                method: "POST",
                data: formdata, 
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function() {
                    alert('upload success');
                },
                error: function() {
                    console.log('upload error');
                }
            }

            )
        }

        );
    }
</script>

<style>
.cropper-crop{
    display:none;
}
.cropper-bg{
    background:none;
}
</style>
<button onclick="crop()">
crop
</button>
```

second file named `upload.php`

```
<?php
$croppedImage= $_FILES['croppedImage'];
$to_be_upload=$croppedImage['tmp_name'];
$new_file= 'cropped-Image.PNG'
move_uploaded_file($to_be_upload, $new_file);
echo 1;
?>
```

Comment: Whats `print_r($_FILES)` show?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone where do i put this?

Comment: This works to me. Check the direcoty permission in where you saving the file.

Answer (score 0):

I think first parameter of move_uploaded_file should be $_FILES['croppedImage'] and also, $_FILES is expecting a file object and I am not sure you are sending the right data.

Comment: tried changing it to $_FILES['croppedImage'] ['tmp_name'] but it didn't work :/

Comment: Well, I think it's the data format then. I suggest you to convert cropped image in base64 and do the rest on the server through ajax.